# how to publish code from VSCode to Dynamics 365 Business Central production environment

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'm writing code in Al extension for Dynamics 365 Business Central in VS Code and trying to publish it to **strong text**production environment(sandbox i tried and it worked) that stores data to Azure.
Now publishing thing to **production** environment is tricky part and I don't know how to do this really. If anyone has experience with azure and business central, i would be really grateful for any type of help :)
P.S I read some of Microsofts documentation on learn.microsoft.com but I still don't get it

Answer (score 1):

Mohana answered my question, I am really grateful for his help. If anyone gets in trouble with the same question, here is the answer just in case.

> We cannot install code from VScode to Production environment.
> We have to upload the app file through the Extension management page.
>
> -Mohana

http://mohana-dynamicsnav.blogspot.in/

https://www.facebook.com/MohanaDynamicsNav